# Disabling the back button with an alertbox?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, back-button

I have an alert box for a log in and when ever the back button is pressed the alert box disappears. I've tried `@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // do nothing.
        }` but it still just stops the back on the activity not the alertbox. Is there something special i have to do to disable the back button on the alertbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `setCancelable()` is intended for this...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Comment: Yep, `builder.setCancelable(false)` will do it. The default is `true`.

Comment: The default is true, but oddly the default snippet for Dialogs that can be found in Motodev sets it to false.